# Как сделать отступ от элемента с position fixed?

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать отступ от элемента  у которого задано свойство -  `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var t = parseInt($('.fixed').css('top'));
var l = parseInt($('.fixed').css('left'));

//задаем нужные нам отступы
sleva = l + 80;
sverxu = t + 80;
$(".relative").css({
  left: sleva,
  top: sverxu,
})
```

```css
.fixed {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 25px;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.relative {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed">Я зафиксирован</div>
<div class="relative">А я зафиксирован относительно тебя</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left:10px -от левой стороны вправо на 10 пикселей
right:10px -от правой стороны влево на 10 пикселей
top:10px  - от самой верхней точки вниз на 10 пикселей
bottom:10px - от самой нижней видимой точке вверх на 10 пикселей.
или используйте
margin-left:10px
margin-right:10px
margin-top:10px
margin-bottom:10px
```

Comment: Это отступ от элемента???